# Laravel: Pass a variable to a tab without using Javascript

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am building an index page in whicgh I show the orders separated in three tables: "incoming", "in_progress", "ready"

Essencially is this same table shown three times (and separated into a different tab)

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover dataTables-example">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Eingang</th>
            <th>Auftrag id</th>
            <th>Ort</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($all_ as $element)
        @if($element->status === 'in_progress')
        <tr>
            <td>{{$element->id}}</td>
            <td class="gradeX">{!! $element->created_at->format('D j M Y, G:i:s') !!}</td>
            <td><a href="{{route('orders.show', $element->title)}}">{!! $element->title !!}</a></td>
            <td>{!! $element->address->plz->locality !!}</td>
        </tr>
        @endif
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I saved the table in a different file and I called it like this:  **@include('dashboard.orders.includes.table_orders')**

```
....
<div class="tab-content py-3 px-3 px-sm-0" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
        <!-- I need to call here the partial and pass status="incoming" -->
        @include('dashboard.orders.includes.table_orders')
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
        <!-- I need to call here the partial and pass status="in progress" -->
        @include('dashboard.orders.includes.table_orders')
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
        <!-- I need to call here the partial and pass status="ready" -->
        @include('dashboard.orders.includes.table_orders')
    </div>
</div>
```

The model looks lilke this:

```
$element [
    "id" => 1
    "title" => "KFZ_0001_May_2019"
    "details" => "Lorem Ipsums dolor..."
    "status" => "in progress"    // <---or incoming or ready
    "created_at" => "2019-05-31 09:14:02"
    "updated_at" => "2019-05-31 11:16:55"
    "deleted_at" => null
  ]
```

The question is:

**How do I call the external partial and pass the "status" variable in order to show the orders separated each in its corresponding table?**

All the three tables are show in the same page!

I would like to avoid using of javascript just for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I understood you, I would do something like this:

```
@include('dashboard.orders.includes.table_orders', ['status' => 'incoming'])
```

and then

```
@foreach($all_ as $element)
    @if($element->status === $status)
        ...
    @endif
@endforeach
```

If you want to output some data three times and the difference just in some variables, you won't break DRY principle.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a variable to the blade file included just by passing an array as the second parameter:

```
<div class="tab-content py-3 px-3 px-sm-0" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
        @include('dashboard.orders.includes.table_orders', ['status' => 'incoming'])
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
        @include('dashboard.orders.includes.table_orders', ['status' => 'in_progress'])
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
        @include('dashboard.orders.includes.table_orders', ['status' => 'ready'])
    </div>
</div>
```

and inside your `table_orders` template:

```
@foreach($all_ as $element)
    @if($element->status === $status)
    <tr>
        {{ .. your row format }}
    </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

If you want to further generalize your code, without the need to repeat 3 times the same inclusion and to easily add different statuses, you could pass to the view an object such as:

```
$tabs = [
  ['status' => 'incoming', 'id' => 'nav-home', 'label' => 'nav-home-tab'],
  ['status' => 'in_progress', 'id' => 'nav-profile', 'label' => 'nav-profile-tab'],
  ['status' => 'ready', 'id' => 'nav-contact', 'label' => 'nav-contact-tab'],
];
```

and in your view:

```
@foreach($tabs as $tab)
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="{{ $tab['id'] }}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="{{ $tab['label'] }}">
        @include('dashboard.orders.includes.table_orders', ['status' => $tab['status']])
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This takes the answer further. Thanks. My code is reduced so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this `@include('partial_name', $element)`

Then you can access the variable as the name you passed to the include

Comment: I could pass three variables, as a second argument ($incoming, $in_progress and $ready). However, I will need still to copy and paste three times the same table, one per each variable which is basically the same problem. No DRY code.